# Polar to Cartesian returning strange results

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, coordinates, polar-coordinates

I'm not sure if it's my maths or my Python which isn't up to scratch... but the code below is giving unexpected results. It still plots a circle of points, but in a strange order and a non-uniform manner (even allowing for int rounding errors) i.e. the points aren't sequential around the circle as degree increases, they jump to entirely different points on the circle?

```python
def pol2cart(distance, angle):
    x = distance * numpy.cos(angle)
    y = distance * numpy.sin(angle)
    return(x, y)

for fixedangle in xrange(0,360,10):
    x, y = pol2cart(50,fixedangle)      
    print str(int(x)) + ", " + str(int(y)) + "  " + str(fixedangle) + "\xb0"
```

A sample of the result:

```python
50, 0  0°
-41, -27  10°
20, 45  20°
7, -49  30°
-33, 37  40°
48, -13  50°
-47, -15  60°
31, 38  70°
-5, -49  80°
-22, 44  90°
43, -25  100°
-49, -2  110°
40, 29  120°
-18, -46  130°
-9, 49  140°
34, -35  150°
-48, 10  160°
46, 17  170°
-29, -40  180°
```

If 0 degrees = (50,0) then I would expect 10 degrees to be around (49,9) not (-41,-27). And i'd expect 20 degrees to be ~(47,18) not (20,45)... etc. Just with those three examples you can see the Cartesian point has jumped to a completely different quadrant then back again. Even if my ideas about rotation direction, or starting point are completely wrong, I still expect each point to be rotationally sequential either clockwise or anti-clockwise from the 0 degree start point. Plus you can tell from the "square" angles 90 and 180 that the Cartesian point is far from perfectly horizontal or vertical in relation to a (0,0) central point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like numpy is working in radians, not degrees

Comment: aah thanks Jeremy. And thanks all: ticked the first one :)

Answer (score 2):

The functions of `sin()` and `cos()` of numpy take inputs in radians instead of degrees. Converting the degrees to radians should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, only problem is that the numpy.cos(angle) takes its argument in radians, not degrees. You can either change the tester to range from 0 to `2*numpy.pi` or convert the degrees to radians by adding `angle = 180*angle/numpy.pi` on line 2.